# Keyframes Animation has no transition when moving in other direction (Pure CSS)

Tags: html, css

I have this Keyframe Animation where i move a dot in a square:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#dot {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  animation: moveDotOne 2s infinite;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

@keyframes moveDotOne {
  0% {
    top: 0;
  }
  25% {
    top: 20px;
  }
  50% {
    left: 20px;
  }
  75% {
    top: 0;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="dot"></div>
```

The only problem is that the 25% keyframe is already running when the 0% isn't even finished. How can i fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out you need to think about both x&y positions for the transitions - added variables here to make the effect easier to observe. At each keyframe a x and y position (top,left) are specified.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

:root{
  --d:80px;
  --w:90px;
}


#box{
  padding:1rem;border:1px solid red;
  width:var(--w);
  height:var(--w);
}

#dot {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  animation: moveDotOne 5s infinite;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  margin:1rem;
}

@keyframes moveDotOne {
  0% {
    top:0;
    left:0;
  }
  25% {
    top:var(--d);
    left:0;
  }
  50% {
    top:var(--d);  
    left:var(--d);
  }
  75% {
    top:0;
    left:var(--d);    
  }
  100%{
    top:0;
    left:0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='box'>
  <div id="dot"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Think about what the animation is making it transition the value **from**.

When it hits `50%` it sets `left: 20px`. So it then transitions from **something** to `20px`. What is that something?

You haven't specified anything. So it is the default value.

You can't transition from `auto` so it jumps.

---

Set starting values for `left` and `top` in your CSS. Don't assign them **only** with the animation.

Comment: Thank you so much! The only problem is that its running fine but the f.e. the 25% animation is already running when the 0% isn't even finished

Comment: @JustChillinInDaHood — The animation runs in 2 seconds. There are 4 transitions. 2 divided by 4 is not 0.3s.